# Rcpp: Combining Vectors into Matrix and printing rows using Rcout

Tags: r, rcpp

I have the following code in Rcpp:

```
NumericVector s_1 = NumericVector::create(0,0,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,0);
NumericVector s_2 = NumericVector::create(0,-1,0,-1,1,1,0,2,-2);


// [[Rcpp::export]]
void print_vecs(){
  NumericMatrix mat(2,9);
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++){
    Rcpp::Rcout << mat.row(i); // Not working Trying to print the row
  }
}
```

So Basically I am trying to see how to combine `s_1` and `s_2` into a `NumericMatrix`, and then go through the matrix and print the rows. Also are there simple tutorials for Rcpp? I have found some tutorials, but they are too advanced for me. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
mat.row(0) = s_1 ;
mat.row(1) = s_2 ;
```

You cannot send rows of the matrix to `Rcpp::cout`, what you can do is print the matrix, something like this:

```
Rf_PrintValue(mat) ;
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any tutorials for beginners?

Answer (score 2):

To complement Romain's answer, matrix operations are *really* well supported in Armadillo and easily accessible via RcppArmadillo.

Here is a variant for you:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void printVecs(arma::rowvec v1, arma::rowvec v2) {
  arma::mat m(2,9);
  m.row(0) = v1;
  m.row(1) = v2;
  m.print("Matrix m");

  // or equally well (where you could also print v1 and/or v2
  Rcpp::Rcout << "Matrix M\n" << m; 
  }
}

/*** R
 v1 <- c(0,0,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,0)
 v2 <- c(0,-1,0,-1,1,1,0,2,-2)
 printVecs(v1, v2)
*/
```

You can just source this directly

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("/tmp/mat.cpp")

R>  v1 <- c(0,0,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,0)

R>  v2 <- c(0,-1,0,-1,1,1,0,2,-2)

R>  printVecs(v1, v2)
Matrix m
        0        0  -1.0000   1.0000  -1.0000   1.0000   1.0000  -1.0000        0
        0  -1.0000        0  -1.0000   1.0000   1.0000        0   2.0000  -2.0000
Matrix M
        0        0  -1.0000   1.0000  -1.0000   1.0000   1.0000  -1.0000        0
        0  -1.0000        0  -1.0000   1.0000   1.0000        0   2.0000  -2.0000
R>
```

As for your question regarding tutorials: yes, there are. Use a search engine; you should find plenty.  I also [wrote a book](http://www.rcpp.org/book/) on this.

Comment: Thanks. I know you have put a lot of effort into Rcpp and thanks again for that. I am looking for the fastest possible performance. Are operations in RcppArmadillo faster than regular operations using Rcpp NumericMatrix?

Comment: There should not be a measurable difference in the time taken to _run_ the code.  But for certain tasks I find Armadillo faster to _write_ than plain Rcpp code (but there are counter example where I prefer Rcpp and sugar).  Just pick one (or both), learn one (or both) and move on actually getting stuff done.